# How to get/set working directory for nsIProcess runAsync()

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing a Firefox extension using the Addon SDK that needs to launch a bash script and then read its output from a file it creates in the current directory as follows:

```
echo "bash script output" >file.txt
```

I am launching the bash script as follows in my main.js:

```js
function runBashScript(scriptFile) {
    var localFile = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
        .createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile)
    localFile.initWithPath('/bin/bash');

    var process = Cc["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
        .createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);
    process.init(localFile);

    var args = [ scriptFile ];
    var rc = process.runAsync(args, args.length, 
        function(subject, topic, data) {
            console.log('subject=' + subject + ', topic=' + topic + ', data=' + data);
            console.log('bash script finished executing, returned ' + process.exitValue);
    });

    return rc;
}
```

My question is how do I find out programatically, from within main.js, where file.txt will be stored when the script echoes to it? So what's the current working directory of the launched process? And is there anyway to retrieve it or change it?

The documentation on [nsIProcess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nsIProcess) online doesn't mention anything about this.

I have determined (by searching the FS) where file.txt ends up when running the extension using cfx run, and when running it in Firefox after installing it as an XPI. But I would like to determine this info at startup and maybe even control where it ends up being stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of `nsIProcess` - it will always execute applications using the application-wide current directory. You can get this directory using [`nsIDirectoryServiceProvider` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDirectoryServiceProvider):

```js
var currDir = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
                .getService(Ci.nsIDirectoryServiceProvider)
                .getFile("CurWorkD", {}).path;
```

The issue in your case is still that this directory will usually not be writable. While you could change this directory via js-ctypes, this is definitely not advisable - you might break other code that relies on the current directory not changing. The alternative is to let bash change the current directory before executing the script:

```js
var args = ["-c", "cd /tmp && . " + scriptFile.replace(/\W/g, "\\$&")];
```

Note that the `replace()` part is important to escape all unusual characters - otherwise parts of the file name might get interpreted as an additional command.

Comment: Thank you Wladimir! This answers my question. In my case, the CurrWorkD directory seems to be writable, since the file.txt files are always created and written to successfully. I will simply have my script echo to /tmp/file.txt, instead of file.txt. Seems like a simpler compromise :)

Answer (score 0):

The open call gives the path to the file.  If you fail to give the full path it will default to the current working directory of the process running the command.  A process can change its current working directory using a system call, so where it is when it starts may not be the same later on.  If you care where the file goes, you should specify the full path.

To write the file to a temporary directory on Unix/Linux do:

```
echo "bash script output" >/tmp/file.txt
```

You should not write the file to, for example, the user's home direetory since it may overwrite a different file of the same name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In runBashScript, I pass the parameter of the script using require('self').data.url('script.sh') which I translate to a full path using toFilename in require('api-utils/url'). The end result is that script.sh gets invoked as: /tmp/tmpihluZS.mozrunner/extensions/my-extension-id@jetpack//resources/my-extension/data/client.sh (when running with cfx run) and as /home/alin/devprofile/extensions/my-extension-id@jetpack//resources/my-extension/data/client.sh (when running after installing the XPI in firefox)

Comment: But, in the first case, file.txt gets stored in the current directory where i am running cfx run from.
In the second case, when running from firefox after installing XPI, file.txt gets stored in ~/alin/file.txt

Comment: The working directory of the process is not the location of the executable.  The two are not related.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the distinction. I was telling you how they were invoked in the two different scenarios using /bin/bash <full_script_path>, so you could see that file.txt ended up in different locations (once in ~/alin and the other time in the directory where I ran "cfx run" from). This seems to indicate the launched process' working dir depends on some other variables here.

Comment: You're correct, this is because the environment we set up in cfx run is distinctly different. If you would like to avoid this difference, consider using Wladimiar Palant's 'Extension Auto installer' extension - you can use this to test extensions rapidly while avoiding these differences: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/autoinstaller/

Comment: I see, thank you! That plugin would help with this actually. Still, I'm wondering if there is a way to control or to retrieve the working directory of the launched process? If not, can I at least rely that it'll always be in the home directory of the user (for when the extension is installed as an XPI)?

Answer (score 0):

There is now [subprocess](https://github.com/bit/subprocess), which allows you to do this.